# Scale each cell in Mat using min and max

Tags: c++, opencv

I couldn't figure out a function for scaling all cells in cv::Mat using a given range. It seems to be a quite useful function, or should I do it manually iterating through the matrix?

What I actually want to do is to scale a traning data for CvSVM. Each column has individual range of cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin function to do that, but it can be easily accomplished by applying [normalize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) with parameter `NORM_MINMAX` on each [column](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#mat-col).

See the example, where `data` are the original data, and `scaled` is the scaled output, where each column is normalized independently in the range `[0,1]`:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1f data = (Mat1f(3, 4) << 0.1f,  2.f,  30.f,   500.f,
                                 0.55f, 22.f, 330.f,  5500.f,
                                 1.f,   12.f, 3030.f, 50500.f);

    float out_min = 0.f;
    float out_max = 1.f;

    Mat1f scaled(data.rows, data.cols, 0.f);
    for (int c = 0; c < data.cols; ++c)
    {
        normalize(data.col(c), scaled.col(c), out_min, out_max, NORM_MINMAX);
    }

    cout << scaled << endl;

    // Scaled data:

    // 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    // 0.5  1.0  0.1  0.1
    // 1.0  0.5  1.0  1.0

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by calling [**`cv::normalize()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) with **`normType=NORM_INF`**.

Example:

```
cv::Mat data = (cv::Mat_<float>(2, 4) << 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f,
                                         5.f, 6.f, 7.f, 8.f);
cv::Mat res;
cv::normalize(data, res, 1, 0, cv::NORM_INF); // scale to [0,1]
std::cout << res;
```

It will print:

```
[0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5;
 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1]
```

---

***Edit:*** Similar to Miki's approach, you will need to do it on each column if you want different ranges per column.

Assume you want to scale it to `[0, i]` for `i`-th column:

```
cv::Mat data = (cv::Mat_<float>(2, 4) << 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f,
                                         5.f, 6.f, 7.f, 8.f);
cv::Mat res(data.size(), data.type());
for (int i = 0; i < data.cols; ++i) {
    cv::normalize(data.col(i), res.col(i), i+1, 0, cv::NORM_INF); // scale to [0,i+1]
}
std::cout << res;
```

It will print:

```
[0.2, 0.66666669, 1.2857143, 2;
   1,          2,         3, 4]
```